# Conditionals in functions.php not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I disable `auto paragraph` and `br` in all page using this code:

```
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

later on i decided, I want auto `<p>` and `<br />`
behave that way, in `taxonomy => blog-cat` so i came up with this code:

```
 function remove_auto(){
 if(!is_tax('blog-cat')){
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
}
}
add_action('wp_head','remove_auto',0);
```

but unfortunately it's not working.

have anyone have an idea?

Comment: You need to provide more information.

Comment: And what action is this attached to...?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is checking to see if "blog-cat" is not a taxonomy on every request rather than checking to see what the current taxonomy is, and not removing the filters if it is "blog-cat". You can't fetch the taxonomy name using [`get_queried_object()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object)`->name`.

```
function remove_auto(){
    // remove the filter if it is not a taxonomy, or if it is the name doesn't equal 'blog-cat'
    if ( ! is_tax() || 'blog-cat' != get_queried_object()->name ){
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'remove_auto' );
```

Comment: I replace my code with the code you suggest but unfortunately it's not working. but anyway thank's for your answer...